# How to create repository for organization using github-api?

Tags: node.js, npm, github-api

I'm using [github-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-api), an npm plugin, to create and manage repositories in node.js. I was able to create repositories for a user, and read a user's organizations, but I could not find out how to create a repository for an organization. I looked through the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create) but I am still confused as to how to create the repository.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this client doesn't support repository creation for organizations. There is only `createRepo` [for user](https://github.com/michael/github/blob/f4c3e6d8045ea567cccdc0802e1769a85c6b690c/github.js#L294).

The request for the user looks like:

`POST /user/repos`

and for the organization:

`POST /orgs/:org/repos`

where `:org` is the organisation name.

Comment: Can I post with jQuery and how can I post with/without jQuery? Thanks so much!

Comment: I ended up just using the Github api's function by doing: github._request("POST", postmessage, options, cb)

Comment: That was an option as well.